# How to programmatically check if database and/or user exists in a PostgreSQL database using Bash?

Tags: bash-scripting, postgresql

I want to write a bash script that creates multiple users and a database.

1. First I want to check if user exist, so I tried

   ```
   sudo -u postgres psql -c 'SELECT 1 FROM pg_roles WHERE rolename=${VAR_USER}'
   ```

   How do I get a return value that I can check in a `if`?
2. How do I check if the database exists?
3. If postgres `psql` have an error, how do I stop the script, and echo the error?
4. I try to create a new variable this way `A='${b}_dml'` but I get an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try something like the following in a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

read -p "Please enter the user name to search for: " VAR_USER

VALUE=$(psql -c "SELECT 1 FROM pg_roles WHERE rolename=${VAR_USER}")
echo "$VALUE"
```

"set -e" causes the script to exit on error. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19622569/9131772) answer and related entries for additional information.  It will also (in my testing with mysql, as I don't have postgres installed) display the error that caused the script to exit.

If using something other than the default database, make sure to specify that database name somewhere/somehow in the script.